UV unwrap doesn't work correctly
I created a cube and extruded one of its faces inside.

When I tried to UV unwrap faces 1 - 5, I got this result:

What I expected however, is this:

As you can see, I've marked all the seams of 5th face, but it looks like the Unwrap ignores it.

How can I fix this and get the UV map I need (3rd image)?

What you expected is unfortunately not always what Blender does by default... by the way, it does not ignore the seams. If seams were igonred, this would mean a UV face would be connected to an adjacent face even though there is a seam between them. This is not the case here. The seams are actually absolutely useless like that, because you've set them only towards faces which are not selected, so they do not get unwrapped and are therefore not connected to the unwrapped face anyway.

I figured out that the reason for this strange behavior is "Fill Holes" option in the Unwrap Menu. If you deselect it, the UV map will not be distorted.

